# Neural network is not predicting correctly

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, prediction

I am making a neural network to predict different kind of vegetables. It keeps predicting the wrong vegetable every time even though my val_accuracy is around 90% .

```
type import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dropouthere

train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
validation = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

train_data_set = train.flow_from_directory(r"C:\Users\roshn\Desktop\Vegetable Images\train",target_size=(200,200),batch_size =15,class_mode='categorical')
```

Found 15000 images belonging to 15 classes.

```
val_data_set = train.flow_from_directory(r"C:\Users\roshn\Desktop\Vegetable Images\validation",target_size=(200,200),batch_size =15,class_mode='categorical')
```

Found 3000 images belonging to 15 classes.

```
train_data_set.class_indices
```

{'Bean': 0,
'Bitter_Gourd': 1,
'Bottle_Gourd': 2,
'Brinjal': 3,
'Broccoli': 4,
'Cabbage': 5,
'Capsicum': 6,
'Carrot': 7,
'Cauliflower': 8,
'Cucumber': 9,
'Papaya': 10,
'Potato': 11,
'Pumpkin': 12,
'Radish': 13,
'Tomato': 14}

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation ='relu',input_shape =(200,200,3)),
                                   tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                                   ##
                                   tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation ='relu'),
                                   tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                                   
                                   ##
                                   tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                   ##
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000,activation ='relu'),
                                   ##
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
                                    ##
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(500,activation='relu'),
                                   ##
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
                                    ##
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(250,activation='relu'),
                                   ##
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(15,activation='softmax')])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer ='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy',patience=2,verbose=1,mode='max')
mc = ModelCheckpoint('checkpoint/',monitor='val_accuracy',mode='max',save_best_only=True,verbose=1)
lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy',factor=0.1,min_lr=0.001,patience=15,mode='max',verbose=1)




model_fit=model.fit(train_data_set,
                  epochs=10,
              batch_size=64,
              validation_data=val_data_set,
              callbacks=[es,mc,lr],validation_split =0.2)
```

```
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "sequential_23"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_63 (Conv2D)          (None, 198, 198, 16)      448       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_63 (MaxPoolin  (None, 99, 99, 16)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_64 (Conv2D)          (None, 97, 97, 32)        4640      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_64 (MaxPoolin  (None, 48, 48, 32)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 flatten_22 (Flatten)        (None, 73728)             0         
                                                                 
 dense_54 (Dense)            (None, 1000)              73729000  
                                                                 
 dropout_8 (Dropout)         (None, 1000)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_55 (Dense)            (None, 500)               500500    
                                                                 
 dropout_9 (Dropout)         (None, 500)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_56 (Dense)            (None, 250)               125250    
                                                                 
 dense_57 (Dense)            (None, 15)                3765      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 74,363,603
Trainable params: 74,363,603
Non-trainable params: 0
___________________________________________________
```

This is the code I used for prediction.

```
dir_path =r"C:\Users\roshn\Desktop\Vegetable Images\train\Bitter_Gourd\0001.jpg"
img  =image.load_img(dir_path,target_size =(200,200,3))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

x= image.img_to_array(img)
x=np.expand_dims(x,axis =0)
images =np.vstack([x])
vl = model.predict(images)

t = train_data_set.class_indices

classes = list(t.keys())

values = t.values()


list_index=list(values)
x=vl
for i in range(15):
  for j in range(15):
    if x[0][list_index[i]] > x[0][list_index[j]]:
      temp=list_index[i]
      list_index[i]=list_index[j]
      list_index[j]=temp

print(list_index)



for i in range (5):
  print(classes[list_index[i]],':',round(vl[0][list_index[i]])*100,"%")
```

Comment: You did not apply to new images the 1/225 rescaling that you applied to the training set.